# Vue 3 + TypeScript TS2614: Module '"*.vue"' has no exported member

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, export, vuejs3

I'm trying to make named export in one component like this:

```
export interface ITest { t: String }
```

to call it from another:

```
import { ITest } from '@/components/Test.vue'
```

And have the error:

`TS2614: Module '"*.vue"' has no exported member 'ITest '. Did you mean to use 'import ITest from "*.vue"' instead?`

And if I change to:
`import ITest from '@/components/Test.vue'`

The error now says:
`Module '"(path)/Test.vue"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { ITest } from "(path)/Test.vue"' instead?`

How to make named export in Vue using TypeScript?

Vue 3, TypeScript, Webpack 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
export interface ITest { 
  t: string; 
}
```

- Change `Test.vue` to `Test.ts`, and where import it as well.
- Change type `String` to typescript type `string`

Comment: Is this answer solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Don't export at setup section.

The following works:

```
<script lang="ts">
export interface ITest { t: string }
</script>
```

I have also wondered this, and didn't find any workarouds, until finally I found this by myself.

You can take a look at your `shims-vue.d.ts` and you can find it's probably analizing setup block to infer the definition of a component behind the scene.

That is to say, the setup block defines the type `DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>`, so there may be no spaces for exporting any static type. Thus I tried to export it in pure script block, and it worked.